# Azure Connection Error with Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage

I have the Azure Storage (v3.4) and Compute Emulator (v2.5) installed, and I can check my deployments in the Compute Emulator ok , but whenever I try to visualize the contents of my tables or blobs, I get the following error from Visual Studio:

Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, but may be wrong, Storage 3.4 and Compute Emulator 2.5 are part of Azure SDK 2.3.

I am not sure of the cause, but I fixed this issue buy reinstalling Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2013 version 2.3. It's **WindowsAzureTools.vs120.exe** that lives here http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42317.

I also deleted all versions of Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio I had installed before reinstall, I had 2.5 and 2.6. I vaguely remember that the "downgrade" install is not allowed for this package.