# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I hate to turn to StackOverflow for troubleshooting these types of things, because I feel that most issues should be able to be resolved through spending time Googling around for similar issues, but I've had so many issues with Azure that it's driving me insane.

I have just opened a brand new project, Cloud > MCV4 > ASP.Net Web Role. Rather than make any changes, I've just went to run it straight away to see if it works - it should. However I get this error message:

Could not load file or assembly 
    'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=4.0.0.0,
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
    The system cannot find the file specified.

Now, I've had a look online and saw another Stack Q about this, here:

[Azure Connection Error with Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856459/azure-connection-error-with-emulator)

I did have Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 v2.8 and
Microsoft Compute Emulator v2.8 - but I have since downgraded them to match the versions in the link provided, however, I'm still having no success.

Anyone have a similar issue or can give me a couple of other things to try.

I've tried this both on VS2013 and VS2015 same error message

Comment: Oh well, looks like I'm stuck with it forever

Comment: are you referencing the dll? if so can you tell me what version it is?

Comment: This happened to me 6 months ago and only a clean install of the OS helped. Today it happened to me again.

Can't believe no one had an answer for this.

Comment: I did a fresh install of my OS to resolve the issue and eventually got VS2015 to work if I remember correctly. I had needed the software to complete a coursework assignment and it cost me quite a lot of time. Hope you manage to find a fix soon though

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with expanding `Azure / Storage / (Development)` branch  in `Server Explorer` window in VS2015.

Solved by uninstalling (via Add-remove programs) **Azure Storage Emulator** (v4.6 currently) and installing older one - v4.5 from older SDK. I used [August 2016 (version 2.9.5) version of Azure SDK for .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/) (file `AzureStorageEmulator.msi` from there).

Now my VS2015 and 2017 works OK.